# How to sleep in a firefox extension without using setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying to open a pop-up window, wait X seconds and then close the popup window.

(The use case is sending a notification to a webapp  - but we can't just do a GET request as it needs to be in the same session so we can use the login session)

I can't use `setTimeout` as we can't use it in add-ons/extensions

How can I get similar functionality without resorting to chewing up CPU cycles, which obviously causes a noticeable lag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use nsITimer.

A basic example is below but you can find more information (including the use of Components.interfaces.nsITimer.TYPE_REPEATING_SLACK as an alternative to setInterval) on the relevant documentation page at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsITimer

```
// we need an nsITimerCallback compatible interface for the callbacks.
var event = {
  notify: function(timer) {
    alert("Fire!");
  }
}

// Create the timer...  
var timer = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/timer;1"]
    .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsITimer);

// initialize it to call event.notify() once after exactly ten seconds. 
timer.initWithCallback(event,10000, Components.interfaces.nsITimer.TYPE_ONE_SHOT);
```

Comment: I found this eventually anyway - works brilliantly - thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Since firefox 29 sdk/timers module provides a CommonJS API

Comment: For Firefox 22+ you could use the simpler Timer.jsm. It's similar to the add-on SDK approach but works in non-SDK addons and older browser versions. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Timer.jsm

Answer (score 10):

You can use the [timers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/timers.html) module provided by the SDK instead of `nsITimer` for the same kind of setTimeout/setInterval functionality provided in browsers

```
let { setTimeout } = require('sdk/timers');

function openPopup () {}

setTimeout(openPopup, 3000);
```

Comment: Definitely the preferred option since Firefox 29.